# Twistd TAP change log verbosity

Tags: python, twisted

I am currently writing an application that is meant to be started using Twisted's twistd script as a plugin.

However my code is currently very verbose logging quite a bit of information. When running my application a a twistd pluging is there any way that I can filter the log messages and offer different levels of log verbosity to the user?

### Update

After digging through all the twisted logging documentation I've decided to reduce the verbosity by using global flags to disable log messages.

So to rephrase my question it would have to be how can I reduce the verbosity of twisted itself. Currently twisted tells you every time a factory is created or destroyed, along with a lot of detail. I would like to reduce this verbosity, and also change the way additional detail is displayed.

Also it would be nice if I could add logging levels to my code, instead of completely disabling log messages, but this is not necessary.

Hope this clears things up a little bit.

Comment: There's not enough detail in this question.  What logging system are you using?  What verbosity levels are defined in your log messages?  Are you trying to filter based on a command line option or something else?  Did you have any log levels or filtering before you started using twistd?

Comment: @Jean Updated my question to help clear things up, I hope. But I have to admit that I'm having difficulty articulating my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a factory to not tell you when it builds a new protocol, you can just set its noisy to False. See http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-11.0.0/twisted/internet/protocol.py#L35 -- I am not sure if this is what you were asking.